# JavaScript Form Validation - specific field entry needed but in upper/lower case

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a simple form with a single field which essentially works like a password, only letting a user to the next page when they click submit, if the correct 'referral code' is entered in the field.

I need the my JS validation code to allow the word 'garlic' be entered in upper or lower case or a mixture of both to pass the validation. Only 'garlic' can be used as  the referral word though. The below code is what I have currently but it only specifically validates 'garlic' in all lower-case.

Any assistance in being able to validate one word in upper and lower-case and both together would be much appreciated.

```
function ValidateContactForm() {
    var codeentry = document.form1.code;
    if (codeentry.value == "") {
        window.alert("Our apologies, the code does not match our records; please call us");
        codeentry.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (codeentry.value !== "garlic") {
        alert("Our apologies, the code does not match our records; please call us.");
        codeentry.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make both upper (or lower) case, then do the compare.

```
codeentry.value.toUpperCase() !== "GARLIC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following condition

```
else if (codeentry.value.toLowerCase() !== "garlic")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the toLowerCase() after the value!

```
function ValidateContactForm()
 {
var codeentry = document.form1.code;

if (codeentry.value == "")
{
    window.alert("Our apologies, the code does not match our records; please call us");
    codeentry.focus();
    return false;

}

else if (codeentry.value.toLowerCase() !== "garlic" ) {

    alert("Our apologies, the code does not match our records; please call us.");
    codeentry.focus();
    return false;

}


 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
else if (codeentry.value.toUpperCase() !== "garlic".toUpperCase() ) {

alert("Our apologies, the code does not match our records; please call us.");
codeentry.focus();
return false;
}
```